# Wordpress wp_query() basic question about args

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

Can someone tell me the comparison of these three query statement:

1/ Is it nline code ? I don't know what is it call.

```
$getposts->query('post_type=projects&taxonomy=projects_categories&post_status=publish&showposts=-1&field=term_id&terms='.$cat_id);
```

2/

```
$args2 = array(
                        'post_type' => 'projects',
                        'taxonomy' => 'projects_categories',
                        'posts_per_page' => 9,
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order'   => 'DESC',
                        'terms' => $cat_id,

             ); 
$getposts->query($args2);
```

3/

```
$args3 = array(
          'posts_per_page' => 9,
          'orderby' => 'date',
          'order'   => 'DESC',
          'post_type' => array (
                            'projects' => 'projects',
                          ),
           'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'projects_categories',
                  'terms' => $cat_id,
                )
            )
        );
$getposts->query($args3);
```

Why my 1st and 2nd code doesn't work in my case. I have to use the 3rd one to display all the post (custom post type) that belong to the taxonomy that have $cat_id

I google and someone have the same problem that they can't display post in taxonomy. Finally they use some similar to the 3rd code. Can someone show me how to switch back and forth and when we should use the 1st, 2nd or 3rd query.

Why sometime we use 'post_per_page' and sometime we use 'showposts'?

Thank you

Comment: The first example is using query string syntax. It might work, but I'm not sure if it properly supports taxonomy queries, but regardless, there's no good reason to be using that syntax these days. It just makes it harder to read and debug.

Answer (score 2):

Your 3rd option is correct.

```
$args3 = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    // If you're only specifying one. Use array( 'projects', 'post' ); for many.
    'post_type'      => 'projects',
    // This is the correct syntax for a taxonomy query. 
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'projects_categories',
            'terms'    => $cat_id,
        ),
    ),
);
$getposts->query( $args3 );
```

The other options you have posted here are old methods that are no longer valid for custom taxonomy queries. Always reference to [WP_Query Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to make sure you're using the latest parameters.

As for your second question, `posts_per_page` replaced `showposts`. `showposts` is no longer valid.

Comment: Thank you, your response is very helpful. So from now on I have to use 'tax_query' to request custom taxonomy data ?

Comment: Correct. WordPress still has support for categories and tags in the way you posted, but not custom taxonomies.